# Border-Radius with position absolute images (no overlap)

Tags: overflow, css-position, css, overlap

I've got a  inside  and 's. My problem: the outer div got border-radius and overflow: hidden. The images are wider than it's parent . But overflow: hidden works well to hide the rest of the image. Only the border-radius works not on the images. Why?

My HTML structure:

```
<div class="teaser-container tc1-sidebar">
<a href="#"> 
<img class="teaser-image bottom" src="dist/img/teaser/bigteaser-bonus-hover.jpg" alt="teaser"><img class="teaser-image top" src="dist/img/teaser/bigteaser-bonus.jpg" alt="teaser">
</a>
</div>
```

CSS for outer :

```
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
   -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
   -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
```

CSS for inner 's:

```
position: absolute;
-webkit-border-radius: 10px;
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

Thanks for any workaround!

Look at my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/7h4SD/

Comment: Please give exact names of classes or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7h4SD/ ;-)

Answer (score 0):

see if this works simple work around

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UyxKW/)

CSS ---

```
    .box-s1 {
    width: 360px;
    height:360px;
    border: 1px solid #515355;
    margin: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 60px;
    background: url('http://weirdmovievillage.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/dexter-main-iamge1.jpg');
}
```

HTML

```
 <!-- 
* basic problem: image is wider than box. 
* round-corners don't grip 
-->

<div class="teaser-image-box box-s1 tib-ef1">

</div>
```

Let me know if the workaround doesnot suit you. Basically setting the height and width will be equal to the image height and width :) you can also keep the image added to check its height but change visibility

```
display:none
```

In case you want the image to be there :)